# UITableView (Section)Footer has always maximized width

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to build a facebook app style login view. The Problem is my footer views has always full width and not the width I set them to have in the interface builder.

The login button is the section footer. The register button is the tableView footer.

1. How I can make the buttons smaller (in width)?
2. I want the register button at the button of the view. How do i do this?
   [image]

Comment: Quite a name of an application ! SEDUCE ME ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the button and other views in a separate view. In `viewForFooterInSection:`:

```
UIView *wrapper = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:aSuitableFrame];
UIButton *loginButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
loginButton.frame = CGRectMake(10,5,self.view.bounds.width-20, 44);
// etc.
[wrapper addSubView:loginButton];
// idem for other views
```